# Are there rewards for translators on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, localization, gamification

Are there any rewards (eg. badge(s) or reputation benefits) available for the people who contribute to the translations of non-English Stack Exchange sites (eg. Stack Overflow en español) through [Transifex](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/transifex/info)?

If not, would it be possible to add such incentive(s)?

Comment: What're you translating?

Comment: I just edited your question to more obviously refer to Stack Exchange specifically, and replaced the [feature-request] tag with [discussion], since you *appear* to also be asking a question about current features. If you disagree with those changes, please feel free to roll them back, or edit them futher to clarify what you mean a little more!

Comment: Are you talking about Stack Overflow in different languages (e.g., [Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)) and submitting translated questions and answers from one such site to another (in the form of self-answered questions)? Or something else? Can you update your question to make it clearer? For example, you could provide an example to illustrate it. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).

Comment: @Makoto i am SOes

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I mean translations of SO in transifex.